# Can I run ONLY my java file on Linux?

Tags: graphics, java, ubuntu-minimal

Okay, I know (think) I'll have to run Xorg, Xwindowing system, etc. I want to run my java file (I can't reprogram what I have, I must keep it in java and run it on Linux) on Ubuntu Mini. Oh and to make it even more complicated my Java file has graphics and it uses light weight game library/OpenGL. Is there any solutions I can employ?

~Thank you!

Edit: To make it more clear, I have already programmed my code on Ubuntu (not Ubuntu mini). I want to use Ubuntu mini because it is much much more lighter than normal Ubuntu and I am trying to squeeze as much performance as possible. I would like to not have a desktop environment and ONLY (except for necessary background applications) run my java application in full screen. I know this is possible but I do not know the process as I have found links where people have done this with firefox, Libre office, etc.
~Thanks you!^2

Comment: If you want to run a java program on Windows or OSX or Android or another OS, we gently suggest you ask an appropriate support site for that OS. Since your program seems to run on Ubuntu, there seems little that Ubuntu support can help you with.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you found resources explaining how to do it with Firefox, did you try to adapt that to your needs?